# Get current IP addresses associated with an Azure ARM VM's set of NICs via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to write some Powershell to get a list of Azure ARM vms (Not classic) and the currently associated IP addresses for their NICs.

In classic, this was part of the VM object, but in ARM it's a seperate object, and I'm struggling to get the Powershell to work in the way I want.

I've got the following code segment:

```
$nic = (((Get-AzureRmVM).NetworkProfile).NetworkInterfaces).Id
ForEach ($i in $nic) {
  $nicname = $i.substring($i.LastIndexOf("/")+1)
  Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName RGTEST | Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | select-object  PrivateIpAddress,PrivateIpAllocationMethod
}
```

Which works, but only for VMs in the specified resource group 'RGTEST'.

It seems that Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface can only work when passed in the NIC Name and the ResourceGroupName, but I can't seem to get the RGname from the VM to be passed in.

Probably really easy, but I'm struggling with it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use this code to get all my ARM VMs, their private IP address and allocation method, it works across resource groups.

```
$vms = get-azurermvm
$nics = get-azurermnetworkinterface | where VirtualMachine -NE $null #skip Nics with no VM

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $vm = $vms | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $prv =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
    $alloc =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAllocationMethod
    Write-Output "$($vm.Name) : $prv , $alloc"
}
```

Sample Output:
proddc : 10.0.0.4 , Static
stagedc : 10.1.0.4 , Static

Answer (score 2):

Below is the script I used to get the Private and Public IP for an Azure ARM VM. If a VM has more than one NIC or IpConfig it would probably need to use a loop.

```
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "MyResourceGroup01"
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name "MyVM01"
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $(Split-Path -Leaf $VM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].Id)
$nic | Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | Select-Object Name,PrivateIpAddress,@{'label'='PublicIpAddress';Expression={Set-Variable -name pip -scope Global -value $(Split-Path -leaf $_.PublicIpAddress.Id);$pip}}
(Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $pip).IpAddress

#Output:    
Name      PrivateIpAddress PublicIpAddress
----      ---------------- ---------------
ipconfig1 10.0.0.10        MyVM01-pip

40.80.217.1
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that are looking for a solution that works across multiple subscriptions in a tenant, here's a script that loops through each subscription and reports on each private IP, NIC, VM, Resource Group and associated subscription. The output is in object format and is exported to a CSV file.

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Returns IP addresses and associated network interfaces and virtual machines across all Azure subscriptions the
        user has access to.

    .DESCRIPTION
        This script returns all private IP addresses, the IP configuration resources they are associated with, the network interfaces and virtual
        machines across all subscriptions. This script requires:

        1. The Azure module to be installed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.8.0)
        2. The user to be logged in to an Azure account using Connect-AzAccount / Connect-AzureRmAccount
        3. The user must have subscription wide read permissions assigned for each subscription being queried

    .PARAMETER FileName
        Optional. Specify the file name and path for a CSV export.

    .EXAMPLE
        Get-IpAddressAllocation.ps1 -FileName .\AzureIpAddressReport.csv
#>

<#
    .AUTHOR
        Michael Wheatfill

    .LICENSEURI
        https://github.com/mwheatfill/mwheatfill.github.io/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
#>

#region Parameters
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $FileName
)
#endregion Parameters

#region Initializations
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
#endregion Initializations

#region Functions
function Get-IpAddresses {
    param ()

    $networkInterfaces = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object {$_.VirtualMachine -ne $null}
    $virtualMachines = Get-AzVM
    $results = @()

    foreach($interface in $networkInterfaces) {
        $ipConfigurations = $interface.IpConfigurations

        foreach($ipConfig in $ipConfigurations) {
            $vm = $virtualMachines | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $interface.VirtualMachine.Id}

            $ipDetails = [pscustomobject]@{
                PrivateIpAddress = $ipConfig.PrivateIpAddress
                VMName = $vm.Name
                NetworkInterface = $interface.Name
                IpConfigName = $ipConfig.Name
                Primary = $ipConfig.Primary
                ResourceGroup = $vm.ResourceGroupName
                Subscription = $subscription.Name
            }
            $results += $ipDetails
        }
    }
    return $results
}
#endregion Functions

#region Main
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription | Select-Object
$ipAddressesInAllSubscriptions = @()
$progressCount = 0

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    $progressCount++
    $progressComplete = ($progressCount / $subscriptions.count * 100)
    $progressMessage = "Gathering IP address informtion for subscription $progressCount of $($subscriptions.Count)"
    Write-Progress -Activity $progressMessage -Status ($subscription.Name) -PercentComplete $progressComplete

    $subscription | Select-AzSubscription > $null
    $ipAddressesInSubscription = Get-IpAddresses -SubscriptionObject $subscription
    $ipAddressesInAllSubscriptions += $ipAddressesInSubscription
}

$ipAddressesInAllSubscriptions | Sort-Object -Property Subscription, VMName, NetworkInterface, IpConfigName, Primary | Format-Table
$ipAddressesInAllSubscriptions | Export-Csv -Path $FileName -NoTypeInformation
#endregion Main
```

Comment: good :-) would be better to filter by IP but it's not tricky to implement !

Comment: The script exports all Azure VMs, which can then be filtered by Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked back in 2016, Microsoft decided to no longer maintain the `AzureRM` module past [Dec 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0#continued-support-for-azurerm), and along with it, the `*-AzureRM*` cmdlets. The `Az` module replaces it going forward.

However, there's a **fast** alternative for retrieving the list of Azure VMs with their associated IPs (private and public ones), by using Azure Resource Graph (ARG).

Concretely, for several thousand VMs, spread across several hundred Azure subscriptions, it takes **mere seconds** with ARG as opposed to 20+ minutes using `Az`'s `Get-AzVM` cmdlet.

The script further down will report correctly even on multiple vmNics and multiple IP configurations per vmNic. It will retrieve all ARM VM data across the Azure subscriptions in the tenant. If running from either a local Powershell session or Cloud Shell, make sure you have the `Az.ResourceGraph` module installed first.

Sample output on a small test Azure tenant:

[image]

The script follows:

```
function RunARGquery {
    param (
        [string[]]$SubscriptionIds,
        [string]$ARG_query
    )
    
    $fullResultSet = @()
    $pageSize = 5000
    
    # Subscription batching code below taken
    #  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/troubleshoot/general#toomanysubscription
    # Create a counter, set the batch size, and prepare a variable for the results
    $counter = [PSCustomObject] @{ Value = 0 }
    $batchSize = 1000
    # Group the subscriptions into batches
    $subscriptionsBatch = $subscriptionIds | Group -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $batchSize) }

    $currentBatchNo = 0
    # Run the query for each batch
    foreach ($batch in $subscriptionsBatch) {
        $pagesProcessedSoFar = 0
        do {
            $results = @()
            if($pagesProcessedSoFar -eq 0) {
                $results = Search-AzGraph -Subscription $batch.Group -Query $ARG_query -First $pageSize
            }
            else {
                $results = Search-AzGraph -Subscription $batch.Group -Query $ARG_query -First $pageSize -Skip ($pagesProcessedSoFar * $pageSize)
            }
            $pagesProcessedSoFar++
            Write-Host "Processed $pagesProcessedSoFar pages so far. A number of $(($results | Measure-Object).count) results returned in the last page"
            $fullResultSet += $results
        } while(($results | Measure-Object).count -eq $pageSize)
        Write-Host "Finished subscription batch $currentBatchNo"
        $currentBatchNo++
    }
    return $fullResultSet
}

# Get the date/time now, for timestamping both output files
$currentDateTime = Get-Date -Uformat "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"

Write-Host "Getting list of Azure subscriptions..."
# Fetch the full array of subscription IDs
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
$subscriptionIds = $subscriptions.Id
Write-Host "Found $(($subscriptionIds | Measure-Object).count) subscriptions"

# ARG query from Listing 23
$ARM_ARG_query = @"
Resources
    | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
    | project id, vmId = tolower(tostring(id)), vmName = name
    | join (Resources
        | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/networkinterfaces'
        | mv-expand ipconfig=properties.ipConfigurations
        | project vmId = tolower(tostring(properties.virtualMachine.id)), privateIp = ipconfig.properties.privateIPAddress, publicIpId = tostring(ipconfig.properties.publicIPAddress.id)
        | join kind=leftouter (Resources
            | where type =~ 'microsoft.network/publicipaddresses'
            | project publicIpId = id, publicIp = properties.ipAddress
        ) on publicIpId
        | project-away publicIpId, publicIpId1
        | summarize privateIps = make_list(privateIp), publicIps = make_list(publicIp) by vmId
    ) on vmId
    | project-away vmId, vmId1
    | sort by vmName asc
"@
Write-Host "Running ARM ARG query..."
RunARGquery -SubscriptionIds $subscriptionIds -ARG_query $ARM_ARG_query `
    | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty ResourceId `
    | Sort-Object -Property vmName `
    | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "AzureVMs_$currentDateTime.csv"
```

If you're looking to also retrieve the classic Azure VMs (ASM model), using ARG as well, a script is available [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips/#get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-powershell). A detailed discussion around the Azure Resource Graph queries for retrieving the VM data, throttling, permissions, etc can be found in [this post](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/10/01/get-the-list-of-all-azure-vms-with-all-their-private-and-public-ips).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that I use to get relevant VM Private/Public IP Address info used for various tasks.  It will run from MAC OS or Windows OS as I've a MAC with a Widows 10 Parallels VM running for compatibility.  Use it as you wish.

It will export to CSV and attempt to open in Excel or whatever is registered to the CSV extension.  In the example below it was saved as PS_AzureRM_Get_VMs.ps1 or just run it as raw code in PowerShell.

```
#Login to AZURE from PowerShell
#Below works in MAC/Linux PowerShell 6.0.1+ and Windows WMF 4.0+
#pwsh on MAC OS or powershell_ise.exe on Windows
#Connect-AzureRmAccount (Login-AzureRMAcount and Add-AzureRMAccount are the older Azure cmdlets)
# Goto URL https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and the password it provides example Q9KZ3HGN2
#  You may need to select-azurermsubscription -subscriptionid $SubscriptionID #Define $SubscriptionID = 'replace everything with your actual subscription  xxx-xxxx-xxx'

#Example location using the . way of running a script or just cut and paste to PowerShell
#Example location using the . way of running a script
#MAC PWSH syntax
#. ~/Documents/Scripts/AzureRM/PS_AzureRM_Get_VMs.ps1
#Windows PowerShell.exe/PowerShell_ISE.exe syntax
#. $env:userprofile\Scripts\AzureRM\PS_AzureRM_Get_VMs.ps1

$Project="DevOps"
$clientFilePrefix="AzureRM"
$clientFileCampaign="VMs"

#Get Date Time
$Date = ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$Time = ([DateTime]::Now).ToString("HHmmss")
$DateStart=get-date

#Change to Windows Path if running in Windows $env:USERPROFILE
If ($($env:USERPROFILE)) {
  $fldrRoot="$($env:USERPROFILE)\"
  $fldrPathseparator='\'
} Else {
  $fldrRoot="~/"
  $fldrPathseparator='/'
}

# Make Directory if not exist
$fldrPath=$fldrRoot+"Documents"+$fldrPathseparator+$Project+$fldrPathseparator+$clientFilePrefix+$fldrPathseparator+$clientFileCampaign
New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path $fldrPath

#Make Imports Folder
$fldrPathimports=$fldrPath+$fldrPathseparator+"Imports"
New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path $fldrPathimports

#Make Exports Folder Directory
$fldrPathexports=$fldrPath+$fldrPathseparator+"Exports"
New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path $fldrPathexports

#Assign the variable to the export file Prefix
$VMInfo_Export=$fldrPathexports+$fldrPathseparator+$clientFilePrefix+"_"+$Project+"_"+$clientFileCampaign+"_"+$Date+"_"+$Time+".csv"

#Create a Table to use for filtering the results
$VMInfo = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
#Now Add some columns for use later
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'ResourceGroup',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'VM',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Location',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'VM_ID',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'VM_NIC',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'IP',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Public_IP_Name',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Public_IP',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'IP_MAC',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Priv_Dyn',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Status',([String])))
$VMInfo.Columns.Add((New-Object System.Data.DataColumn 'Date_Time',([String])))
$VMInfo_Array_Count=($VMInfo | Measure-Object | Select Count).Count

#List the Array to show it='s empty
Write-Host "Created Array VMInfo with $VMInfo_Array_Count objects"

$Date_Time=([DateTime]::Now).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")+" "+([DateTime]::Now).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
#Check the OS type
If ($($ENV:OS)) {$OSTYPE="WINDOWS";Write-Host "The OS is"$OSTYPE" Based"} Else {$OSTYPE="LINUX";Write-Host "The OS is"$OSTYPE" Based"}
#Get the VM's
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM
$VMstatus = Get-AzureRmVM -Status
#Get the NIC and their properties for matching against the VMs
$NICs = get-azurermnetworkinterface | where VirtualMachine -NE $null #skip NICs with no VM
#Get the Public IPs for matching against the VMs
#Public IPs work only if the naming convention starts with the VM Name used in Azure
$PublicIPs=Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | Select-Object Name,ResourceGroupName,IpAddress

#Now Loop through the NICs in Azure and match against the VMs and the Public IPs
ForEach ($nic in $NICs)
{
    #Get the VM Info
    $VM = $VMs | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $VM_Name = $($VM.name)
    $VM_Location = $($VM.Location)
    $VM_Resourcegroup = $($VM.ResourceGroupName)
    $VM_ID = $($VM.VMid)
    $VM_NIC = $nic.Name -Join ';'
    $VM_Status = (($VMstatus | Where {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq $VM_Resourcegroup -and $_.Name -eq $VM_Name}).PowerState).Replace('VM ', '')
    $VM_IP =  ($nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress) -Join ';'
    $VMPIPName = ($nic.IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id -Split '/')[-1]
    $VM_PublicIP =  ($PublicIPs | Where-Object {$_.ResourcegroupName -eq $VM_Resourcegroup -and $_.Name -like "$VMPIPName"} | Select IpAddress).IpAddress
    $VM_IP_MAC =  (($nic | Select MacAddress).MacAddress) -Join ';'
    $VM_Alloc =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAllocationMethod

    #Uncomment this to check the values before going into the Array $VMINFO
    #Write-Output "$($VM.ResourceGroupName), $($VM.Name), $($VM.VMid), $($VM.Location), $VM_IP, $VM_PublicIP, $VM_IP_MAC, $VM_Alloc"

    #Now populate the $VMInfo array
    $row = $VMInfo.NewRow()
    $row.'ResourceGroup'=$VM_Resourcegroup
    $row.'VM'=$VM_Name
    $row.'VM_ID'=$VM_ID
    $row.'VM_NIC'=$VM_NIC
    $row.'Location'=$VM_Location
    $row.'IP'=$VM_IP
    $row.'Public_IP_Name'=$VMPIPName
    $row.'Public_IP'=$VM_PublicIP
    $row.'IP_MAC'=$VM_IP_MAC
    $row.'Priv_Dyn'=$VM_Alloc
    $row.'Status'=$VM_Status
    $row.'Date_Time'=$Date_Time
    $VMInfo.Rows.Add($row)
}
cls
$TotalTime=(NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $DateStart –End $(GET-DATE))
Write-Host "Script Ran in $($TotalTime.Hours) hours and $($TotalTime.Minutes) minutes and $($TotalTime.Seconds) seconds"

#Export the Info
Write-Host "Exporting VMINFO Report to `n`t$($VMInfo_Export)"
$VMInfo | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $VMInfo_Export

#Depending on OS run the Open/Start command for the CSV Export
If ($OSTYPE -eq "LINUX") {open $VMInfo_Export} `
ElseIf ($OSTYPE -eq "WINDOWS") {start $VMInfo_Export} `
Else {Write-Host "Unknown OS"}

break

#####     ######     #####
#######     ######     #####
##     Extra Tasks to Filter the Exports
#####     ######     #####
#######     ######     #####

#Get the Array Size
$VMInfo_Array_Count=($VMInfo | Measure-Object | Select Count).Count

#ECHO the Array size
Write-Host "`n`n*****     *****"
Write-Host "Array VMInfo has $VMInfo_Array_Count objects"
Write-Host "*****     *****"

break
#Shows Configured Resource Group Names
$VMInfo_ResourceGroupNames=($vminfo | Select ResourceGroup -Unique).ResourceGroup

#ECHO Configured Resource Group Names
Write-Host "`n`n*****     *****"
Write-Host "*****     List of Groups*****"
Write-Host "*****     *****"
$($VMInfo_ResourceGroupNames)

break
#Get DC's from resource Group Name
$VM_Environment="dtdaily"
$VMInfo_GetDCs=$vminfo | where {$_.ResourceGroup -eq $VM_Environment -and $_.VM -like "*dc*"}

#ECHO DC's from resource Group Name
Write-Host "`n`n*****     *****"
Write-Host "*****     List of DC's"
Write-Host "*****     *****"
$($VMInfo_GetDCs)

break
#Get Public IP VMs
$VMInfo_PublicIPs=$vminfo | Where {$_.Public_IP -like "*.*"}

#ECHO Public IP VMs
Write-Host "`n`n*****     *****"
Write-Host "*****     *****"
Write-Host "*****     List of Public IP VMs"
Write-Host "*****     *****"
$($VMInfo_PublicIPs)

break
#ECHO All VMs
$VMInfo

Break
```

Answer (score -1):

I have searched a lot and finally succeeded. Using resource group name and  azure vm name, you can retrieve private or public ip address:

```
$Resourcegroup=""

$VmName=""

$VmNetworkdetails= (((Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup -Name $VmName).NetworkProfile).NetworkInterfaces).Id

$nicname = $VmNetworkdetails.substring($VmNetworkdetails.LastIndexOf("/")+1)

$privateIp =(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $Resourcegroup)|Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPConfigurations 

write-host $privateIp.PrivateIpAddress
```

Comment: Tameem, Can you please tell me how to get the public IP address of my virtual machine. currently i deployed my virtual machine using ARM template.

Comment: This script didn't work for me - seems like wrong syntax